# Relationship not appearing in while using it in another relationship in laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

### I am trying to store checked checkbox data in Laravel Voyager Edit view , but unfortunately eloquent relationship is not showing up while using it in another relationship. To make my problem clear I will show my tables and its relationships

**This is the Tour Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "tours";

    protected $fillable = [
        'address',
        'title',
        'description',
        'primary_image',
        'price',
        'image',
        'index_image',
        'attribute_id'
    ];

    public function tourHasAttr()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TourHasAttribute::class, 'tour_id', 'id');
    }


}

this is the Tour_has_attributes model

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class TourHasAttribute extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tour_has_attributes";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'tour_id',
        'attribute_id'

    ];
    public function attributeTitle()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TourAttributes::class, 'id', 'attribute_id');
    }
}
//This is the Bread controller of voyager which I overrided
   $Tour= Tour::find($id);
        $TourCheckedAttributes = $Tour->tourHasAttr()->get();
        dd($TourCheckedAttributes);
        $allTourAttributes = TourAttributes::all();
        return Voyager::view($view, compact('dataType', 'dataTypeContent', 'isModelTranslatable', 'allTourAttributes', 'TourCheckedAttributes'));
   
}
```

[image: this is how its going to be shown if it's checked or not]

after using dd($TourCheckedAttributes); it clearly shows that the relationship of Tour_has_attributes with tour_attributes is not appearing
[image: dd log]

I was following this tutorial, any help will be appreciated
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BntEU1Q5ga8&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5oPTli631ZX9cxl6cU_sDaR&index=20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you misunderstood the relationship of your models.

```php
$TourCheckedAttributes = $Tour->tourHasAttr()->get();
```

This will return all the tour_has_attr rows under the `$Tour`.

To load all the attributes, you can write

```php
$Tour->with('tourHasAttr')->get();

dd($Tour);
```

Then you will get all the tour_has_attr rows under this Tour.

Comment: Hello,  I want to thank you for your solution, the relationship appeared as expected